# Unable to access values from the table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying get the values from `front, rear, side` attributes from `tints` entity.

manufacturers `{id, name}`
models `{id, manufacturer_id, name}`
tints `{id, manufacturer_id, model_id, front, side, rear}`

This is my `tints_controller.rb`

```
  def generate
    @manufacturers = Manufacturer.find(params[:tint][:manufacturer_id])
    @models = Model.find(params[:tint][:model_id])
    @price_front = Price.find(params[:price][:price_front])
    @price_rear = Price.find(params[:price][:price_rear])
    @measurements = Tint.where('manufacturer_id' => @manufacturers).where('model_id' => @models)
  end
```

I received an error when I was trying to do `<%= @measurements.rear %>` in my `generate.html.erb`

```
undefined method `rear' for #<Tint::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000c628610>
```

Here are the debug screen

```
Request

Parameters:

    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"jfV6SUkNdKWO1f1fyzqS4eLbvszjDPNm2E81M90lnvPArYScSjcjQlxsJdcuqQMJ+mSecCsyVQlhz2cpAH1DUw==",
     "tint"=>{"manufacturer_id"=>"6", "model_id"=>"3"},
     "price"=>{"price_front"=>"1", "price_rear"=>"2"},
     "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

However, when I do `<%= @measurements.inspect %>`, it showed the line below, indicating the `@measurements` in the `tints_controller` is defined correctly. It shows it is able to get the entire row from the table by searching for the correct `model_id` and `manufacturer_id`. But I am unable to get the `front, side, rear` values as in `int` directly by doing `<%= @measurements.front =>`

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Tint id: 1, manufacturer_id: 6, model_id: 3, front: 40, side: 50, rear: 60, created_at: "2016-07-22 04:14:49", updated_at: "2016-07-22 04:14:49">]>
```

What I have done:
I tried to do `<%= @measurements[:front] =>` and `<%= @measurements[:id][:front] =>`, and I still get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select from ActiveRecord using `where`, it returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object, which is **always** an array of the associated objects, because multiple objects can be returned from a `where` query.

You need to either specify which `Tint` to be selected in the view:

```
@measurements.first.rear
```

or you need to modify your controller to only select the first object which is returned:

```
@measurements = Tint.where('manufacturer_id' => @manufacturers).where('model_id' => @models).first
```